# python if statement causing errors

Tags: python, variables, scope

```
someStuff = False
def spawn():
    print(someStuff)
    if( 3==4):
       someStuff = True  
while (someStuff==False):
    spawn()
```

Here's the code, print(someStuff) does not work, it says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'someStuff' referenced before assignment". However, if the if statement is taken out, then it works.

Comment: Is the question about why you're getting this error? I explained that in my answer. But this code as is just gets you in an infinite loop printing `False`...

Comment: Also, the issue isn't the `if` statement but the part where you define `someStuff = True` in `spawn`. If you take out that definition, then `someStuff` just refers to the global variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `someStuff = True` in your function tells Python that you will be creating a local variable `someStuff`.  Python then sees the reference to `someStuff` in `print(someStuff)` before the assignment and complains.  You need to resolve this ambiguity by declaring `someStuff` to be `global`.  Make the first line of you function be `global someStuff`.  Note that doing so means that the later assignment will affect the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

```
def spawn():
     print(someStuff)
```

python will assume that `someStuff` must be a global variable. However, if you have an assignment in your function:

```
def spawn():
     print(someStuff)
     if 3==4:
         someStuff = True
```

then python assumes it is a local variable that needs to be assigned before it is used.

You can let python know it is global by putting `global someStuff` in your function:

```
def spawn():
     global someStuff
     print(someStuff)
     if 3==4:
         someStuff = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange issue with the way global variables work in python.

This change should work:

```
someStuff = False
def spawn():
    print(someStuff)
    if( 3==4):
       global someStuff
       someStuff = True  
while (someStuff==False):
    spawn()
```

For more on why this happens this way: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)